# Middle school science/fantasy book about global scientists who regress to gorillas in order to more easily live off the grid

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book and another by the same author about a teenager with telekinesis and they were amazing. I'd like to find them so I can share with my kids.

I thought the author was named Dale, but was a female. Last name could have been Anderson?

I also thought the name of the book was *The Human Apes*, but I can't find anything when I use that to search.

Comment: The [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) (not Google) is your friend. A title search for The Human Apes works like a charm.

Comment: Yes!!!!!  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [*The Human Apes*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6100354-the-human-apes) by ([Ms.](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/carlson_dale)) Dale Carlson?

> Todd and his friends, Diana and Johnny, are part of an expedition to study the mountain gorillas in Africa. Todd is drawn to a group of gorillas, one of whom speaks to him. **He has discovered the human apes, humans who have spent 6,000 years camouflaging themselves behind gorilla-like characteristics.** In their underground laboratories, their goal is to free themselves from the harmful characteristics of humans, eventually **freeing the mind from the confines of the body into the complete freedom of the universe**. They invite Todd to remain with them. Diana and Johnny remind Todd this means giving up being human.

Comment: In which case the book about telekinesis might be *The Mountains of Truth*.